# Using d3 in sharepoint web interface

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I am building a website for a research center under my university domain. I am trying to create a data-driven document, with autoupdate based on lists. Yet since server-side access to sharepoint lists is blocked by my web manager, and is not about to open; I'm looking for any bypass that would allow: (1) automatic creation of webpages; (2) easy update.

I have written a D3.js  based code which works fine IE 11, firefox, etc. It uses a csv file which I can upload to a library on my server. Yet when I test it on the sharepoint server I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
File: d3.js, Line: 291, Column: 7
```

That is followed by a syntax error implying that `d3` is not a recognized object. All implying that the code failed to load the `d3.js` library. I have tried sourcing it to either the d3 web link or to the library on my web server.

Finally, line 291 column 7 is attached. This is the relvant line `Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, key, {`...

Anyone has an idea how to succefully load d3 to a sharepoint web-content editor?

```
  function d3_class(ctor, properties) {
for (var key in properties) {
  Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, key, {
    value: properties[key],
    enumerable: false
  });
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
As commented below I provide the structure of the code I put into my HTML source of my Content Editor webpart.

It starts with a call for J-query, followed with a call for D3 libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/humsos/negev/jslib/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script> <!-- First error occurs here -->
```

Than, I have my `<style></style>` block and my HTML content. Last I have my js functionality opened by a jquery `$( document ).ready();` call.

Comment: It would help if you show how you are trying to load it. Can you tell if it might just be loading out of order? I've found that it can be difficult to predict what will be loaded first between master page, page layouts, and content webparts.

Comment: @Rothrock - the first two calls (jquery and d3) are at the first two lines of the html source. Than style and html content are provided, followed with a `<script>$( document ).ready( /*functions here*/ );</script>` block. I've edited my question to include those.